# Why My LINQ does not work with multiple Where conditions?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have this sentence linq to filtring a DataTable:

```
string V = @"V";
var DTError = from DTError1 in DT.AsEnumerable()
              .Where(r => ( (r.Field<string>("TIPO_DE_DOCUMENTO") != V) ))
              select DTError1;
```

this linq works; but when I add another condition in the where the linq does not work (See below)

```
string V = @"V";
string M = @"M";

var DTError = from DTError1 in DT.AsEnumerable()
              .Where(r => ( (r.Field<string>("TIPO_DE_DOCUMENTO") != V) )
                             || (r.Field<string>("TIPO_DE_DOCUMENTO") != M))
              select DTError1;
```

Why that is happend?

I know that it's a pretty naab question but the documentacion does not help me.

thanks.

Comment: what is your data source? Are you sure that there are entries that are neither V nor E for 'TIPO_DOC'... as for TIPO_DOC; what sort of a field name is that?

Comment: Always expand on "does not work".

Comment: Your query is essentially looking for records where TIPO_DE_DOCUMENTO is not equal to V or not equal to M.  If it = M then it != V and vice versa so your where will be true for all records.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want an AND operator (&&) instead of an OR (||).

Answer (score 1):

I think you just have a problem with your parentheses you want them all to be inside the first one:

```
.Where(r => r.Field<string>("TIPO_DOC") != V)   
       || (r.Field<string>("TIPO_DOC") != E) )
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try `&&` instead of `||`**

```
string V = @"V";
    string E = @"E";
    var DTError = from DTError1 in DT.AsEnumerable()
                  .Where(r => (r.Field<string>("TIPO_DOC") != V) &&    
                              (r.Field<string>("TIPO_DOC") != E))
                  select DTError1;
```

**OR**

```
 string V = @"V";
        string E = @"E";
        var DTError = from DTError1 in DT.AsEnumerable()
                      .Where(r => (r.Field<string>("TIPO_DOC") != V))   
                      .Where(r => (r.Field<string>("TIPO_DOC") != E))
                      select DTError1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You want in this case indeed to use && instead of ||.

Try expressing in plain language wat you are trying to query with your where-clause...

If I have a collection of cars, and i want to select all cars that satisfy the following condition:

The car is not red  OR the car is not blue

I will get all cars, because any car that does not satisfy the first part (not red) MUST satisfy the the second part (after all, only red cars do not satisfy the first part of the cndition, and red cars are not blue).

I have seen many variations on this in the opposite case, when trying to get all blue cars and all red cars, in which case poeple often use "where color = red && color == blue".
For similar reason, this does not yield the expected result.